# Tryton invalid XML for view / Expecting property name

Tags: xml, tryton

Running Tryton 4.6.2 on MacOS with admin user.

From trytond/modules/quotation/view/quotation_form.xml
(Module not in base Tryton, written specifically for this application.)  Worked in 3.4, fails in 4.6.

Relevant portion of XML is:

```
<group id="deck_group" string="Deck" colspan="6" states = "{'invisible', Not(Bool(Eval('deck_quote')))}">
```

I'm getting:
Invalid XML for view "quotation.quotation".

Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1):

Answer (score 2):

Tryton view definition may change between series. You have all the changes explained on the [migration topic of the discuss server](https://discuss.tryton.org/c/migration).

It's no longer possible to define a PYSON statment on the view The [view_attributes](http://doc.tryton.org/4.6/trytond/doc/ref/models/models.html?highlight=view_attributes#trytond.model.ModelView.view_attributes) function from the model must be used to add pyson statements to the view. You have an example of the required change in [the following commit](http://hg.tryton.org/modules/account/rev/d60176cc48a2). That's explained on the [3.4 to 3.6 migration topic.](https://discuss.tryton.org/t/migration-from-3-4-to-3-6/17)

The previous new version code of your view will look as:

`<group id="deck_group" string="Deck" colspan="6">`

And in the python file of your model you should add:

```
@classmethod
def view_attributes(cls):
    return [('/xpath/to/group'), 'invisible', Not(Bool(Eval('deck_quote'))]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Tryton documentation for 4.6 still refers to **states: A string of PYSON statement that will be evaluated with the values of the current record.

It must return a dictionary where keys can be:

invisible: If true, the widget will be hidden.
required: If true, the field will be required.
readonly: If true, the field will be readonly.
icon: Only for button, it must return the icon name to use or False.
pre_validate: Only for button, . . ..** and in group, it has: **states: see in common-attributes-states.**  IMHO, the doc should be updated and an example shown.

Comment: Yes, but the PYSON it's a python expression that can not be written on XML. You must write the text representation of it, or use the view_attributes to define it with python objects an let trytond convert it to the text representation. I will recommend the latter.

Comment: I don't see how the commit for the migration plan from 3.4 to 3.6 explains the usage of the pyson statement in the .py file from the xml file.  The example referenced only adds a pyson attribute to the xml file, which doesn't work (for me).   Could you supply code and xml examples for before V3.6 using group with states in a pyson statement in the the group element so the group may be made invisible, and V3.6 and after applying 'invisible' in the .py file with a pyson statement.   After trying multiple times, I'm still unable to get this to work.

Comment: The required change is shown on the sample commit I put before. Just look at the python file :http://hg.tryton.org/modules/account/rev/d60176cc48a2#l4.15 and in the view definition file http://hg.tryton.org/modules/account/rev/d60176cc48a2#l9.7

Comment: Adding a pyson statement to each field in a group just doesn't make sense to me, whether it's done in the .py file or the .xml file.

Comment: There is no need to add the pyson statement to each field. You can add the pyson on the group. The pyson will be applied to each element matchin the xpath defined on the first element of the view_attributes function.

Comment: The two files you reference as .py and .xml files appear identical to me.  the only python code in both is move.py.

Comment: Could you please supply before and after examples, using 'invisible'?

Comment: I've edited my reply adding the code sample for newer versions.

Comment: Thanks - that really clarifies things for me.  I'll let you know my result.